# Can't I define a router like "something/somethingelse" in Magento module definition?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.6

I am trying to create my first module in Magento.

The thing that I can't do i sto define a module's route in the way that I want.

I want to create a route "gateways/iphone" and it doesn't works. Is it possible to use "/" in a route definition?

This is my module definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Nacho_GatewayIphone>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Nacho_GatewayIphone>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <nacho_gatewayiphone>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Nacho_GatewayIphone</module>
                    <frontName>gateway_iphone</frontName>
                </args>
            </nacho_gatewayiphone>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And it is working fine in /gateway_iphone, but if I change `<frontName>` value to `<frontName>gateways/iphone</frontName>` when I try to hit /gateways/iphone it doesn't run.

Is it possible to use "/" character in a router definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Magento parses URL to get `router/controller/action`, you can't really specify the router with **/**, since it will violate the above structure.

The answer is pretty easy though, why don't you specify *gateways* as a router, and *iphone* as a controller? You still will need a controller for your module, so instead of creating `IndexController`, you can create `IphoneController` with `gateways` as a router, and get desired `gateways/iphone` in the url.

Comment: works like a charm :) I was believing that "gateways_iphone" was being routed to "IndexController->IndexAction", now I understood how it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If ever you need even more complex URLs then there is a regex-based rewrite method.  For instance you could add the following to your config.xml:

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <nacho_gatewayiphone_example>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/such/a/long/example/for/an/url/path/#]]></from>
            <!-- Assuming that "gateways" is now the frontName -->
            <to>/gateways/example_controller_name/</to>
        </nacho_gatewayiphone_example>
        <!-- Other rewrites for nacho here -->
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

For a little more detail see [this wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller) or for a lot more see [this blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_rewrites_intro).

Answer (score -1):

You should have to rename your module from `Nacho_GatewayIphone` to `Nacho_Gateway_Iphone`.

Make the necessary adjustments to your folder structure and class names.

Comment: and would you please describe how exactly module name is connected to the router?